# How to get specific element in JSON with different key

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

If I have JSON that is:

```
var responses = {customer : {results: 2938; id: 9283}, bredesh : {results: 2938; id: 248}    };
```

I need to do an if in my liste html :

```
<div ng-if="response.(customer and bredesh and all new element (PRobleme is here) ).id=='a'" class="form-group">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to **list all** of the elements of an object and select a specific one with ng-if. To list the keys and values separately use `ng-repeat="(key,value) in your_array"` syntax. Here is a small demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.responses = {
    customer: {
      results: 2938,
      id: 9283
    },
    bredesh: {
      results: 2938,
      id: 248
    }
  }
  $scope.id = 248;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in responses">
    <div ng-if="responses[key].id==id" class="form-group">
      {{key}} - {{value}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="id=248">Select ID: 248</button>
  <button ng-click="id=9283">Select ID: 9283</button>

</div>
```

Otherwise you need to select it manually: `responses.customer.id` and `responses.bredesh.id`